# In .net core razor pages- how do you navigate from parent record page to a child record page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a .net core Razor pages application where I have a parent child relationship.

[image]

The parent is PositionSummary and the Children are PositionDetail.

The PosSumList.cshtml page is a grid/table page like a standard Index Page with the following code:

```
    @page
@model ThePositionerRazor2.Pages.PositionSummary.PosSumListModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "PosSumList";
}

<h1>Position Summary Information</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-page="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary list-panel" id="list-panel">
            <div class="panel-heading list-panel-heading">
                <h1 class="panel-title list-panel-title">Position Summary</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table id="Possumlist-data-table"
                       class="table table-striped table-bordered"
                       style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Possummary[0].PositionNbr)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Possummary[0].WorkTitle)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Possummary[0].Purpose)
                            </th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Possummary)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PositionNbr)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkTitle)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Purpose)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.PositionId">Edit</a> |
                                    <a asp-page="/PositionDetail/Index" asp-route-id="@item.PositionId">Position Details</a> |
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts
    {
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js "></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#Possumlist-data-table').DataTable({ "order": [[0, "asc"]] });

        });
    </script>
}
```

Near the bottom is the line

```
                            <a asp-page="/PositionDetail/Index" asp-route-id="@item.PositionId">Position Details</a> |
```

What I am trying to do is navigate from one folder inside the Pages folder (PositionSummary) to an Index Page inside another folder within the Pages folder (PositionDetail/Index)

When I get there I want that index page to display only the child records related to the parent record selected from PositionSummary.

I am anticipating that it would require me to use a parameter in the OnGetAsync  task in the PositionDetail Index page:

```
namespace ThePositionerRazor2.Pages.PositionDetail
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ThePositionerRazor2.Models.WorkManagerV4Context _context;

        public IndexModel(ThePositionerRazor2.Models.WorkManagerV4Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<Posdetail> Posdetail { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Posdetail = await _context.Posdetail
                .Include(p => p.Importance)
                .Include(p => p.KnowdepthNavigation)
                .Include(p => p.Position)
                .Include(p => p.TimeSpentNavigation)
                .Include(p => p.WorkitemNavigation).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I compile and try to navigate using the above link in the above cshtml code, it doesnt find that page and gives me a 404 not found error when I look at the results in browser doing an F12.

How do you navigate from one folder and page to a different  folder and page in .net core Razor pages? Both the PositionSummary and PositionDetail folders are simply folders inside the standard Razor Page app - 'Pages' folder...

Thanks for any advice. Am suspecting its a routing issue obviously ...

Comment: If this does not solve your problem, you can provide more details about this issue.

Comment: For some reason, the page didn't allow me to comment on your answer above.

The above answer Yinqiu:

just checked it now. Yes -that worked! If I understand correctly the extra period in ../PositionDetail/Index is required to make it look beyond the existing folder of the existing page. Am guessing each additional period takes one further folder up the hierarchy

Thanks

Comment: how do I mark as answer?

Comment: You can see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code like bellow.

```
<a asp-page="../PositionDetail/Index" asp-route-id="@item.PositionId">Position Details</a> |
```